# Why this query and condition return rows

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm working on a large select statement, it was working fine, but with some dates
it gives a strange result, I started reducing it to track the mistake in vain!
until I wrote this code

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
     CURDATE()      AS `Rdat`,
    `p`.`pspsalm1` AS `pspsalm1`,
    `p`.`pspsalm2` AS `pspsalm2`,
    `p`.`pspsalm3` AS `pspsalm3`,
    p.`PSDescription` AS `PSDescription`
FROM
    (`dailyreadings` `d`, `psalms` `p`, `weeks` `w` ,`feasts` `f`)
WHERE      1=2
```

it gives result as well..!
I think this condition ( 1=2) should give no result 
any clarification?

[image]

Comment: are you asking why does this query return some rows?

Comment: Yeah, this shouldn't return any rows.

Comment: yes, that what I'm asking about

Comment: is it an issue in my PHPMyAdmin configuration or what could it be?

Comment: Does the same thing happen on the command line?

Comment: I didn't try the command line, How can I start sql in command line please ?

Comment: Just curious, does 1=0 give the same result?

Comment: the command line gives no result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to you guys
It is a browser issue,
the browser kept the previous criteria and query data using it, even when I changed the condition in the sql statement.
Thanks to you all

Comment: Maybe you were pressing the "Go" button for changing the view settings instead of the "Go" button that's directly under the query window? I find myself doing that about twice per session :)

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't give any result
Try:
refreshing your browser 
clear broser cache and try again